# Overriding variables in Razor views

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm fairly new to the whole AspNetCore MVC scene and I've stumbled into some trouble while writing my html.

I've got the followingL

##### _layout.cshtml

```
@{
    bool showTitle = true;
}

....

if (showTitle)
{
    ....
}
```

##### Page.cshtml

```
@{
    showTitle = false;
}
```

To clairy

I would like to have the title of the page showing by default and have the option to hide it from particular view files. However, I'm not able to overwrite the `showTitle` variable because it is unknown in the view files.

Comment: If you want a quick and dirty way just use a Viewbag else you have to make a new property in your model and pass the model instead

Comment: Do you use  RazorPages or Net Core MVC ? there are 2 tags in your PO. One should be excluded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually solve this by using the inverse logic in _layout.cshtml

```
@if (ViewData["hideTitle"] != null)
{
    ... render something
}
else
{
    ... default behaviour, render something else
}
```

Often used for overriding page titles like this:

_layout.cshtml

```
@if (ViewData["Title"] != null)
{
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] | My Fantastic Website</title>
}
else
{
    <title>My Company | My Fantastic Website</title>
}
```

And you override page title in concrete views like this:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "About Us";
}
```

Views that don't define `ViewData["Title"]`, will get default title `<title>My Company | My Fantastic Website</title>`.

Answer (score 2):

How about putting the variable in the ViewBag and set it in the Controller

**_layout.cshtml**

```
if (ViewBag.ShowTitle == null || ViewBag.ShowTitle == true)
{
    ...
}
```

**Controller**

```
{
     ViewBag.ShowTitle = false;
     return View();
}
```